# How to select data from server and insert it into another server in informix DB

Tags: sql, database, informix, select-insert

If i have two tables with the same structure `Table1,Table2` in different databases `DB1,DB2` in two different servers `S1 And S2`.

How to Select from **Table1** and Insert Into **Table2** with a simple query ?

I try to execute the following  but in vain:

```
INSERT INTO  DB2:Table2
SELECT * FROM DB1@S1:Table1
```

---

I get the following error :

[image]

Comment: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=303711 can perhaps help?

Comment: @Scath :the link is concerning `sqlserver` not `informix`

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to S1 (informix Server 1) the SQL will be executed in that server, which means S1 will need to know where S2 is.

Basically make sure that there is a S2 defined in the sqlhosts file used in S1 (and that you can connect to S2 using the same user you are connecting to S1)

It's not enough to have S1 and S2 defined in the client 'sqlhosts' (server studio) as it is the Informix server (not the client) who will do the connection to S2 for the insert